# Laravel 4.2 First Model Connecting to Eloquent

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, laravel-4, routes

so this is my first time using **Laravel v4.2**

*so confusing because the error.log information is so minim.*

i want to create new Model with name Author

this is my **routes.php**

```
Route::get('authors', 'AuthorsController@IndexAction');
```

this is my **AuthorsControllers.php**

```
<?php

class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function indexAction(){
        return  View::make('authors.index')
            ->with('title', 'Authors and Books')
            ->with('authors', Author::all())
            ;
    }

    public function getView($id){
        return View::make('authors.view')
            ->with('title', 'Author View Page')
            ->with('author', Author::find($id))
            ;
    }
}
```

this is my **Author.php**

```
<?php
class Authors extends Eloquent {
}
```

i got this error log

[20

```
14-10-03 01:37:43] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Author' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-master\app\controllers\AuthorsController.php:11
Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()

#1 {main} [] []
```

I'd like to know where's the problem? because i already followed all of this link page
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#creating-a-view

Please remember that i created the controller with *Authors* and the model with *Author*.

Comment: FYI, the database already created. and i got 4 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
class Authors extends Eloquent {
```

to

```
class Author extends Eloquent {
```

You *might* need to run `composer dump-autoload` after you make the change as well (I cant remember)

Comment: you run it in the root of your app. But make the change to the file first and see if it works - you might not need to run composer after the change.

Comment: so what is the use of that composer dump-autoload?

Comment: composer dump-autoload -o, use to generate class loader, if you add new class, it will not be included in your class loader unless you update it using that dump-autoload.

Comment: @RaffyCortez good answer, so answer my question for Laravel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244277/why-is-laravel-number-one-framework